# Capifony Error reading response length from authentication socket - linux

Tags: linux, git, ssh, ssh-keys, capifony

I have created a configuration on one machine (ubuntu) that works and checks out code from repo, now I try to duplicate the same configuration on another machine.
I have configured ssh to the point when I can issue:

```
ssh -Tv git@gihub.com
```

And I get correct response:

```
Hi <myrepo>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

I can see which key is taken for authentication. I also can checkout code from repo manually.
But when Capifony runs checkout code it ends up with:

```
Error reading response length from authentication socket.
```

I have already upgraded net-ssh gem to 2.9.1, tried with ssh-add (although I have forwarding set up in /etc/ssh/ssh_config).
It looks like Capfiony does not see ssh authentication configuration that works from command line, how can it be ?